# Find out sum of TOP 10 function

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-tablix

Hello I am trying to present the data in a matrix format & I am using TOP N in the table level. The tabular data in Desc order & I want to divide the top 10 numbers with their subtotal but it is considering total of entire data set.

Using the formula - =RunningValue(Fields!Total.Value,Sum,"DataSet3")/2439 I am getting the view but if I use a filter it will give wrong result.

Please suggest what we can use instead of 2439 so that after using filter it will be an automated process & using sum of those TOP 10.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Aggregates within an SSRS table is that they act on the filtered and sorted dataset, not the original SQL dataset, depending on where the SSRS filter and sorting is applied. In general, if you want to do calculations on a subset of your data, it's handy to have a unique value in the SQL dataset on which you can group and run SSRS aggregates.

If you're trying to do a group by X, you could try doing a [row_number() over (partition by [x] group by [y] desc)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and then use the following formula. In this formula, it would group the data into groups of whatever @X is (e.g., if @X is ten, then you'd have 0 for the first group of ten, 1 for the second group, 2 for the third group, etc).

```
Floor((Row_Number() over (Order by [rowID]) - 1)/@X) as Row_Grouping
```